link button to apex class
I'm having an apex class for executing while clicking a custom button I've created in the list view of object records. But I'm not able to connect the apex class with custom button since javascript execution is not supported in lightning. How to do this

You can still use buttons that point to a Visualforce page, but the current approach would be something like calling an @Auraenabled() static method.
The relevant section of documentation is here

You could make a flow, have the button point to the flow and then kick off the apex from the flow. In this way you could have a little confirmation dialog box to ensure that it was clicked intently. You never want to automatically start something from a button or else it could start by accident.
